# How to regex_match # (hash symbol) in c++?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am reading .C and .CPP files in C++. Currently using BOOST for recursive_directory-iterator.

My question is im trying to use regular expressions to extract #define variables in a C file. but the regex does not match at all. How to regex_match(#define)???

Note: regex is just std::regex and not boost::regex

code snippet:

```
            //input stream file
            ifstream inFile(path.string(),ios_base::in);

            //reading file line by line
            while(getline(inFile,readLine))
            {

                //Excluding comments
                if(regex_match(readLine,regex("\\/|;|\\*")))
                {
                    //ignore do nothing
                }
                else if(regex_match(readLine,regex("#")))
                {
                    cout<<"regex # matched"
                }
```

tried regex_match(readLine,regex("#"),   regex_match(readLine,regex("^#"),  regex_match(readLine,regex("^\#")--> # is not special but still just wanted to check
regex_match(readLine,regex(".#")

nothing matches.. can anyone help pls???

EDIT: im using VS2012 , windows 8

**UPDATE: ".*#.*" works good... thank everyone**

Updating here so that everyone who has a doubt like me can view it easily.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the regex pattern

"#.*"

This pattern will match a # followed by any number of characters until newline and is working for all my testcases (although very few) assuming I got the question right.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) says:

```
The entire target sequence must match the regular expression for this function
 to return true (i.e., without any additional characters before or after the match).
 For a function that returns true when the match is only part of the sequence,
 see regex_search.
```

So it should be the below one to match with entire string:

```
else if(regex_match(readLine,regex(".*#.*")))
```

or, if `#` at the beginning of the line.

```
else if(regex_match(readLine,regex("^#.*")))
```